# Solr : Importing data with single SP call

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have one solr collection called document.
In that there are fields like

```
id,name,associated_folder,is_associate & other
```

The field is_associate depends on associated_folder.

I am importing data using Data Import provided in Solr Dashboard
My problem is that Stored Procudeure which returns data like :

```
#   id      name        associated_folder   is_associate
1   DOC1    DOCNAME     1001,1002,1003      true
2   DOC2    DOCNAME     4001,4002,4003      true
3   DOC3    DOCNAME     -1                  false
```

& in my schema file **associated_folder** declare like :

```
<field name="associated_folder" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false"  termOffsets="false" default="-1"/>
```

field type is int for **associated_folder**  & SP returns the comma separated String value for **associated folder id** 
& it is better for me to make one SP call & set information for Document as performance concern.

I don't want to make extra stored procedure call for get associated_folder/is_associate

Is there any way using which I can import all fields using single SP **with existing schema** ?

Thanks for looking here..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your import configuration for the Data Import Handler, you can add `transformer="RegexTransformer"` to your `<entity>` definition, and then use `splitBy=","` on the field to split it into multiple values.

```
<entity name="foo" transformer="RegexTransformer" .... >
    ...
    <field column="associated_folder" splitBy="," />
</entity>
```

See the documentation for [RegexTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer).

Comment: Thanks for solution. But, I got following String Instends of my value [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@c00aff9] when I import data in solr

Comment: @mcacorner That is an implementation issue with JTDS which isn't present in Microsofts own driver, but you can try setting `useLobs` to `false` as an option when creating the JDBC connection.