# How to deal with compound keys using dih in solr

Tags: solr

I am importing data from mysql db into solr documents. All is fine but I have one table which has a compound key (a pair of columns together as primary key) -> primary key for **post_locations** table is **(post_id, location_id)**.
 But my post_id is the primary key for my solr document, so when data is being imported from post_location table the location_ids are being overwritten.Is it possible to get location_ids(which is of type int) as an array(as there can be more than one location_id for a post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL you can use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the values for a field grouped together in a single column, separated by `,`. You can then use the `RegexTransformer` and `splitBy` for that field to index the field as `multiValued` (in practice indexing it as an array). I posted [an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758064/solr-importing-data-with-single-sp-call/24758342#24758342) in a previous answer. You might also do this by having dependent entity entries in DIH, but it will require more SQL queries than doing a `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`.

If you want one row for each entry, you can use build a custom `uniqueKey` instead, using `CONCAT` to build the aggregate / compound key on the MySQL side.